# Echo checked if checkbox is checked

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

if this is my checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Filter[]" value="Steak" id="Filter"/>
```

and if checkbox is checked var_export returns me

```
["Filter"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "Steak"
```

how do I echo "checked=checked" if checkbox is checked?

Comment: [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [empty()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) come to mind; like `if(!empty(...))` or `if(isset(...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$checked = in_array('Steak',$_POST['Filter']) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="Filter[]" value="Steak" id="Filter"'.$checked.'/>';
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `in_array()`, this will check whether that value exists in the array, if your array contains the value, the function will return true and you can simply `echo` out the `checked` attribute

```
if (in_array('YOUR_VALUE_HERE', $arr)) {
   echo 'checked="checked"';
}
```

You can also make a function passing value and array as parameter and returning the value from the function.

Comment: function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument. what i did wrong?

Comment: @user2635574 you are not passing array at `$arr` parameter, you need to use your actual array at the place of `$arr`

Comment: @Mr.Alien, this answer works great if the checkbox is actually checked. If the checkbox is not checked an error occurs "Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null". Do you know how to correct this error if the checkboxes are left empty? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php // Check if the box was sent.
  $checked = "";
  $status = (isset($_REQUEST['status']));
if ($status == 'checked' )  
{
  $status = 1;
  $checked = 'checked="checked"';
}
else
{
  $status = 0;
}
  echo $status; 
  echo <<<END
 <form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="status" $checked /> Testbox<br />
<input type="submit" onclick="return showDiv();"/>
</form>
END;
?>
```

Comment: The scenario is ..  if i checked the checkbox   and then submit the value is 1  , if unchecked  value is 0..  and its working fine..    so i want to happen is .. i want to get the value 1 and 0 without submitting..    can anyone help me revise my code pls..

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your problem

$checked = in_array('Steak',$_POST['Filter']) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
echo '';